# What's wrong with my code

Tags: spi

I use a mega as a master and a nano as a slave.
Both should convey texts. However, I get the master always only the answer that I send.
The text from the slave does not arrive.

Master:

```c++
#include <SPI.h>
volatile boolean senden;
volatile char Paket_vom_Slave;
volatile char Paket_zum_Slave;
char buf [100];
volatile byte pos;
String Paket = "";
char x;


void setup (void)

{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  //SS Pin auf HIGH setzten
  SPI.begin ();  //Verbindung starten
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);  //Geschwindigkeit verlangsamen
}

void loop (void)
{
  //Text_erstellen();

  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);    //starten der Kommunikation mit Slave

  for (const char * p = "TxT v Master\n" ; Paket_zum_Slave = *p; p++)
  {
    //Text_erstellen();
    Paket_vom_Slave = SPI.transfer(Paket_zum_Slave); //senden von Text
    Text_erstellen();
    delayMicroseconds (500);
    Serial.print("sent: ");
    Serial.print(Paket_zum_Slave);
    Serial.print("\t empfangen: ");
    //Serial.println(Paket_vom_Slave);
    Serial.println(Paket);
    delay(200);
  }
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);  //beenden der Kommunikation
  delay (1000);  //kurze pause

}

void Text_erstellen()
{
  char c = Paket_vom_Slave;  //kopieren der Daten von SPI Buffer
  if (pos < sizeof buf)
  {
    buf [pos++] = c;  //hinzufuegen des naechsten Zeichens
    if (c == '\n')
      senden = true;
  }
  if (senden)
  {
    buf[pos] = 0;
    Paket = (buf);
    x = buf;
    Paket.trim();
    Serial.println (("empfangen :--->") + (Paket));
    Serial.println (("empfangen :--->") + (Paket));
    Serial.println (("empfangen :--->") + (Paket));
    pos = 0;
    senden = false;

  }
}
```

Slave:

```c++
#include <SPI.h>
volatile boolean senden;
volatile boolean versandbereit;
//volatile byte Paket_Master,Sendung_Slave;
volatile char Paket_Master;
volatile char Sendung_Slave;
String Paket = "";
String Sendung = "";
int i = -1;
char buf[20];
char buf1[20];
volatile byte pos;
volatile byte pos1;


void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);


 pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);
 SPCR |= _BV(SPE);         // turn on SPI in slave mode


  //SPCR |= bit (SPE);
  senden = false;
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);   // turn on interrupts
  SPI.attachInterrupt();
}

void loop(void)
{

  if ((versandbereit) == false);
  {
    Paket_Text();
  }

  if (senden)
  {
    i = i + 1;

    buf[pos] = 0;
    Paket = (buf);
    buf1[pos] = 0;
    Sendung = (buf1);

    if (i == 12)
    {
      SPDR = "\n";
    }
    else
    {
      SPDR = (buf1[i]);
    }
    Paket.trim();
    Sendung.trim();
    Serial.println (("empfangen :--->") + (Paket));
    Serial.println (buf1[i]);
    Serial.println (i);
    Serial.println (("gesendet  :--->") + (Sendung));

    pos = 0;
    senden = false;
  }

  if (i == 12) i = -1;
}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{

  byte c = SPDR;  //kopieren der Daten von SPI Buffer
  if (pos < sizeof buf)
  {
    buf[pos++] = c;  //hinzufuegen des naechsten Zeichens
    if (c == '\n')
      senden = true;
  }
}

void Paket_Text()
{
  if (pos1 < sizeof buf1)
    for (const char * p = "Paket--Slave\n" ; char c = *p; p++)
    {
      buf1[pos1++] = c;
                            Serial.println (buf1);
      if (c == '\n')
        versandbereit = true;
    }
}
```

I've updated the code above.
The slave now sends bitwise the same text length as it should, but another text like the master sent.
Unfortunately, the master always receives what he sends, not what comes from the slave.

---

I'm getting on slowly :-)

But I currently have a problem with the data transfer.
I hand over at startup: char package_to_master [50] = "Start from the slave.";
and change SPI interrupt routine content with "new text"
but is sent "starting from the slave."
How should I change that?

```c++
// Slave
char Paket_zum_Master[50] = "Starten vom Slave.";
volatile int pos;
volatile bool active;
String Send_Paket;
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)    // SPI interrupt routine
{
  Send_Paket = "neuer Text";
  char Sendung = ((Send_Paket + "\n").c_str());
  Paket_zum_Master[50] = Sendung;
  byte c = SPDR;
  if (c == 1)  // starting new sequence?
  {
    active = true;
    pos = 0;
    SPDR = Paket_zum_Master[pos++];   // sendet erste byte
    return;
  }
  if (!active)
  {
    SPDR = 0;
    return;
  }
  SPDR = Paket_zum_Master[pos];
  if (Paket_zum_Master[pos] == 0 || ++pos >= sizeof(Paket_zum_Master))
    //wenn pos=0 oder größer 1
    active = false;
}  // end
```

Comment: Pin 10 at the nano and the master pin 53 but the hardware exchange is ok, I've already checked

Comment: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892&reply=1#reply1

Comment: Unrelated, but a more-descriptive title might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have `pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);` in `setup()` of the master.

Comment: digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

Comment: I think with the command it happened:

Comment: I tried it once but the problem persists :-(

Comment: to use digitalWrite  pinMode must be set

Comment: do not set it to output on slave. on slave the SS pin is handled by hardware

Comment: Yes Mega Master Pin52 Nano =pin10

Comment: did you add pinMode(SS, OUTPUT); to setup() on master?

Comment: pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);   SPI.begin ();  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8); is registered but it is not yet

Comment: if it worked for a moment, check the wiring. ground is connected between boards?

Comment: I try to explain the mistake again, maybe someone has an idea for me.
I send to Master "TxT v Master \ n" at the character "\ n" the slave gives me the message correctly.
The slave sends back ____ "package - slave \ n", but the master only shows me the text he sends himself.
When I send something without a "\ n" character from the slave, the master does not put any text together
void text_create () no cancel. But since the slave sends the same character length, the transmission seems obvious.
When composing, however the master only puts together what he sends. Do I have the worm somewhere

Comment: Paket_vom_Sklave; is clearly the valid return and with "\ n" the slave comes with the demolition.
In case of an invalid return but not.
I hope my explanation is understandable Mfg Dieter

Comment: If I have to change the pin mod how do I do that where I am still a stupid. Maybe someone can tell me where exactly I have to enter.

Comment: try the examples by Nick Gammon in the link I added in a comment to the question. the code is very similar to yours, but not same

Comment: If I have to change the pin mod how do I do that where I am still a stupid. Maybe someone can tell me where exactly I have to enter.

Comment: Nick Gammon seine Beispiele sind gut die hab ich aber schon hin und her gelesen und probiert leider ist es mir nicht gelungen da ein Nutzen raus zu bekommen. Mir fehlt noch einiges an Erfahrung.

Comment: Nick Gammon his examples are good but I have already read back and forth and tried unfortunately I did not succeed in getting a benefit out. I still lack a lot of experience. oh sorry was not englisch bevor

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on with Arduino Pro Micro as a master and Arduino Uno as a slave. It is working.

[image: SPI micro uno]

In the 'Note about Slave Select (SS) pin on AVR based boards' https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI, it is notified that the SS pin should be set always as OUTPUT, even though you use another one to select the device.

The answer contains the text inside the SPI data register, you have to change it inside isr https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-fast-can-spi-slave-reply, else it is the same text as that received

```
const char *p = "Reponse Uno\n" ;
ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  byte c = SPDR;  //kopieren der Daten von SPI Buffer
  buf[pos++] = c;  //hinzufuegen des naechsten Zeichens

  if (pos < 13) 
    SPDR = p[pos-1];
  else
    SPDR = 0;

  if (c=='\n') {
    for (int i=0;i<pos;i++)
        bufi[i]=buf[i];
    posi = pos;
    pos = 0;
    senden = true;
  }
}
```

The result is
[image: Uno respondo]

By the way, it is another issue to make it work with Arduino Pro Micro as a slave ...

Comment: the problem is he doesn't set the SS as output even he uses it to select the slave

Comment: Yes it works for me so far but in the master with you, the slave sends the same synonymous yes the same back what he sends. The master should actually receive another text.

Comment: Added the way the master can get another text to the answer.